# Remove 'accounts' tab for unregistered users

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, user-accounts, unregistered-users

Considering that [unregistered users can't have their accounts associated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95287/95288#95288), can you remove the **accounts** tab from their profiles?