# Do merged unregistered users get notifications from all merged accounts?

Tags: support, notifications, unregistered-users

So from [Do unregistered users get notifications?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95287/do-unregistered-users-get-notifications) I know unregistered users get notifications. But I've got a user who keeps coming back as an unregistered user (and being merged into the same user so we can keep track). I'm trying to contact the user via comments before a mod message is necessary, but he's replied to some, not all, comments.

If user A gets a notification without checking it, loses their cookie and creates user B, then  A and B are merged, will user AB still have that notification from before their cookie was lost? I'm particularly interested in comment and possibly mod message notifications.